# Qt examples fail to run on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt

I am beginner on Qt,i just installed the last version with Qt creator.
I choose Calculator example or create new Application and when i build i always got the same errors:

```
cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

Could someone help me to overcome those errors?
Thank you

Comment: You need OpenGL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html#debian-ubuntu-apt-get) is pointed out in ubuntu you have to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev
```